# javascript split things to save in two parts in different locations

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, hta

Hey scripter i have here in my hta an array which is loaded and saved to a text file. Now i want to change this and want to store the first line of the file in this location: 
`strUserProfile & "/CAD_Kunde.txt"` and the rest of the part in this location: `i:\CAD_Kunden.txt`. My problem is i dont now how to split this array because both parts are needed in the same function. User Teemu has done most changes on my script. Hope someone can help me. Here is my code for better understand:
**EDIT: @all stop klicking vote down i didnt now how to explain my question and my english is not the best**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>CATIA Starttool</title> 
<HTA:APPLICATION  
     ID="myCATIA"  
     APPLICATIONNAME="myCatia" 
     SCROLL="no" 
> 
//****** Check if CAD_Kunde.txt exists when not create file
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript"> 
Option Explicit  
Set objShell=CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strUserProfile=objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")  
dim filesys, filetxt, objShell, strUserProfile
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8  
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If not filesys.FileExists(strUserProfile & "/CAD_Kunde.txt") Then 
    Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(strUserProfile & "/CAD_Kunde.txt", ForWriting, True)  
    filetxt.WriteLine ("1")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("BEHR;B18 SP4;B18 SP7;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("AUDI;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("BMW;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("BIT;B18 SP4;B19 SP3;B16 SP9;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("CHRYSLER;B18 SP4;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("CAE_64;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("CNHTC;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("DAF;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("DASSAULT;B18 SP7;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("DFCV;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("FORD;B18 SP4;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("FREIGHTL;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("FUSO;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("HINO;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("HONDA;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("IVECO;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("MAN;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("NISSAN;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("MB;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("PACCAR;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("PORSCHE;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("PORSCHE_HYBRID_DX;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("PSA;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("RENAULT;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("RVI;B18 SP4;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("SCANIA;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("TELCO;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("UD_TRUCK;B17 SP4;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("VOLVO_CAR;B18 SP4;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("VOLVO_TRUCK;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("V5_MM;B18 SP4;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("V5_BM;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("V5_TEST;B19 SP9;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("VW;B19 SP3;0")
    filetxt.WriteLine ("")
    filetxt.Close 
End If

</script>

//****** Open last used environment and set it as default selection 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

// Reads textfile, file is created automatically, if not exist 
function readCustomers(){ 
var fso,iStream,cust,n,tarr; 
shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); 
userPath=shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%UserProfile%');
customers={}; 
fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'); 
iStream=fso.OpenTextFile(userPath+'/CAD_Kunde.txt',1,true);
cust=iStream.ReadLine(); 
for(n=0;!iStream.AtEndOfStream;n++){ 
    tarr=iStream.ReadLine().split(';'); 
    customers[n]=new Customer(tarr);         
} 
iStream.Close(); 
customers[0].selectionElement.selectedIndex=cust; 
alert(cust);
    customers[cust].createReleaseOptions(cust); 
window.activeCustomer=cust; 
return; 
} 

// Customer (environment) constructor function 
function Customer(txt){ 
    var n,x=0; 
    this.selectionElement=document.getElementById('select1'); 
    this.customerName=txt[0]; 
    this.catiaRelease=[]; 
    for(n=1;n<txt.length-1;n++){ 
        this.catiaRelease[n-1]=txt[n]; 
        x++; 
    } 
    this.len=x; 
    this.defaultOption=parseInt(txt[txt.length-1]); 
    this.selected=false; 
    this.createCustomerOption(); 
} 

// Creates customer (environment) options 
Customer.prototype.createCustomerOption=function(){ 
    var opt; 
    opt=document.createElement('OPTION'); 
    opt.text=this.customerName; 
    opt.value=this.customerName; 
    this.selectionElement.add(opt); 
    return; 
} 

// Creates release options 
Customer.prototype.createReleaseOptions=function(idx){ 
    var target,n,opt; 
    target=document.getElementById('select2'); 
    target.length=0; 
    for(n=0;n<this.len;n++){ 
        opt=document.createElement('OPTION'); 
        opt.text=this.catiaRelease[n]; 
        opt.value=this.catiaRelease[n]; 
        target.add(opt);     
    } 
    target[this.defaultOption].selected=true; 
    //target[0].selected=true; // Move comment line above, if this option is used 
    window.activeCustomer=idx; 
    return; 
} 

// Saves textfile 
function saveCustomers(){ 
var fso,oStream,n,m,str='',cust=document.getElementById('select1');eos=cust.length; 
fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'); 
oStream=fso.OpenTextFile(userPath+'/CAD_Kunde.txt',2,true); 
oStream.WriteLine(cust.selectedIndex); 
for(n=0;n<eos;n++){ 
    str=''; 
    str+=customers[n].customerName+';'; 
    for(m=0;m<customers[n].len;m++){ 
        str+=customers[n].catiaRelease[m]+';'; 
    } 
    str+=customers[n].defaultOption; 
    oStream.WriteLine(str); 
} 
oStream.Close(); 
} 


function OpenAction(object) { 
   self.resizeTo(299,299); 
   OpenActionVB(); 
   readCustomers(); 

} 

function RunScript(object) { 
   saveCustomers(); 
   BetriebssystemKommando(object.select1.options[object.select1.selectedIndex].value, 
                          object.select2.options[object.select2.selectedIndex].value, 
                          select3=document.getElementById('OSName'), 
                          object.select4.options[object.select4.selectedIndex].value, 
                          object.select5.options[object.select5.selectedIndex].value, 
                          object.select6.options[object.select6.selectedIndex].value); 
}
```

Comment: this question is unanswerable in it's current form. in general, if your code snippet has a scroll bar, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @user1225282 You still having this problem? If I've understood right what you trying to do, it is not going to work. You need to put this "Environments"-file to your server, and save the default selection of the "Environment" to user's profile folder. Then MANUALLY update the "Environment"-file when needed. If you save the "Envoronment" to the server and all works stations, there will soon be a conflict between these files.

Comment: @Teemu maybe a just asked the wrong question. I want so save the latest selection in Environment from the latest run of the script in a file on the current user profile and the standard dropdown layout of Environment on the server. Is this possible and how? I want to keep the current function of the script.

Comment: @user1225282 I've made changes to original JavaScript functions. But we'll loose the ability to save default release selections, only environment selection can be saved. You can't use automatic saving for "Environment" except one single time. It is even much easier to update the text-file only, instead of your code. Shall I post the code as answer?

Comment: please post it as answer i will test it tommorrow and mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, once again :) .

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
// ** CREATE CUSTOMER-OBJECT
function Customer(txt){
    var n,x=0;
    this.selectionElement=document.getElementById('select1');
    this.customerName=txt[0];
    this.catiaRelease=[];
    for(n=1;n<txt.length;n++){
        this.catiaRelease[n-1]=txt[n];
        x++;
    }
    this.len=x;
    this.selected=false;
    this.createCustomerOption();
}

// ** CREATE CUSTOMER OPTIONS
Customer.prototype.createCustomerOption=function(){
    var opt;
    opt=document.createElement('OPTION');
    opt.text=this.customerName;
    opt.value=this.customerName;
    this.selectionElement.add(opt);
    return;
}

// ** CREATE RELEASE OPTIONS
Customer.prototype.createReleaseOptions=function(idx){
    var target,n,opt;
    target=document.getElementById('select2');
    target.length=0;
    for(n=0;n<this.len;n++){
        opt=document.createElement('OPTION');
        opt.text=this.catiaRelease[n];
        opt.value=this.catiaRelease[n];
        target.add(opt);
    }
    target[0].selected=true;
    window.activeCustomer=idx;
    return;
}

// *** SAVE DEFAULT SELECTION FOR CURRENT USER ONLY
function saveCustomers(){
    var fso,oStream,n,m,str='',cust=document.getElementById('select1'),eos=cust.length,shell,userPath;
    shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
    userPath=shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%UserProfile%');
    fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    oStream=fso.OpenTextFile(userPath+'/DEFCATIASEL.txt',2,true); // * SAVE THE DEFAULT SELECTION
    oStream.WriteLine(cust.selectedIndex);
    oStream.Close();
    return;
}

// *** READ ENVIRONMENT FROM SERVER AND DEFAULT SELECTION FROM CURRENT USER FILE
function readCustomers(){
    var fso,iStream,cust,n,tarr,shell,userPath;
    customers={};
    shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
    fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');    
    userPath=shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings('%UserProfile%');
    iStream=fso.OpenTextFile(userPath+'/DEFCATIASEL.txt',1,true); // * READ THE DEFAULT SELECTION
    try{
        cust=iStream.ReadLine();
    } catch(e){cust=0;}
    iStream.Close();
    iStream=fso.OpenTextFile('YOUR_SERVER_PATH/CAD_Kunde.txt',1,false); // * READ ENVIRONMENTS AND RELEASES FROM SERVER
    for(n=0;!iStream.AtEndOfStream;n++){
        tarr=iStream.ReadLine().split(';');
        customers[n]=new Customer(tarr);
    }
    iStream.Close();
    customers[0].selectionElement.selectedIndex=cust; // * SELECTS THE DEFAULT ENVIRONMENT
    customers[cust].createReleaseOptions(cust);
    window.activeCustomer=cust;
    return;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

For this system you have to remove the "release numbers" from CAD_Kunde.txt. So you'll use a file looking like this:

```
BEHR;B18 SP4;B18 SP7
AUDI;B19 SP3
BIT;B18 SP4;B19 SP3;B16 SP9
```

This file should be manually updated (with text editor) for new environments or releases.

Comment: Thanks Teemu it is doing exactly what i want. I add for me to prevent errors a part which creates the DEFAULTSEL.txt in userprofile when it not exist. Yeah and thats what i wanted the CAD_kunde.txt on the server to add global new environtments and realeases when its needed. I have marked your answer as the right one.